# PHP. Поиск подстроки в строке

Tags: php

Сервер отдает ответ в подобном формате, занесем в переменную:

```
$string = 'Данные в системе отсутствуют, потому что не введены';
```

Нужно чтобы работало так:

```
если $string содержит 'отсутствуют' И 'не введены' {
 //выполнить
}
```

Как решить?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Уже и порешал

```
if(stristr($exit, 'отсутствуют') !== FALSE && stristr($exit, 'не введены') !== FALSE) {
    //выполняем
}
```

Comment: Гуглится это быстрее, чем оформляется вопрос...

Comment: @ВладимирМартьянов да, изначально вопрос был про регулярки, и перерос в это.

Answer (score 2):

strpos два раза вас определенно спасет.